# dividir un Result=> en Angular 6

Tags: angular

Hola estoy tratando de dividir un `result` en Angular y no puedo le agradeceria si me pueden ayudar primero les muestro el jsn que necesito capturar y dividir.

```
[{"Fecha":"2018-09-14","Peso":"331"},{"Fecha":"2018-09-05","Peso":"480"},{"Fecha":"2018-08-16","Peso":"277"}]
```

Ahora le muestro lo que hice en el componente y no me funciona

```
this.PesaSer.seleccionarPesajeIDTAG(idtag).subscribe(
  res=>{  
    this.Peso.Peso=res   
    const {Fecha,Peso}=this.Peso      
    console.log(Peso.Peso);
    console.log(Fecha);
  });
```

he probado varias forma y no logro separar las 3 Fechas y los tres Pesos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas recibiendo es un arreglo de objetos, es por eso que no puedes acceder como lo haz intendado.

Si conoces los valores que recibiras podrias hacer:

```
res[0].Fecha //obtener la fecha del primer elemento del arreglo
res[1].Peso //obtener el peso del segundo elemento del arreglo
```

Si los valores que vas a recibir son dinamicos (no conoces la cantidad que llegara o si llegaran), tienes que cambiar un poco tu logica (por lo que alcanzo a ver en el codigo que mostraste).

Con un `forEach` podrias recorrer los elementos del array para trabajar cada uno de ellos, de esta manera:

```
res.forEach((item) => {
    //a este punto 'item' contiene cada par de fecha y peso
    //aqui podrias hacer:
    this.Peso.Peso = item.peso
    //Solo ten en cuenta que este valor se sobreescribiria por cada item del arreglo
});
```

Comment: this.Fecha=res[0].Fecha******
      this.Peso=res[0].Peso******
      
      this.Fecha+=res[1].Fecha*******
      this.Peso+=res[1].Peso**********

      this.Fecha+=res[2].Fecha********
      this.Peso+=res[2].Peso**********                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                      
             Con esto solucione solo me faltaría agregar una coma entre valor

Comment: 2018-09-142018-09-052018-08-16
331480277                               Por consola me entrega todo los valores pegados

Comment: el res.forEach me da este error  "Cannot find name 'res' "

Comment: @Adrian a caray, si te funciona lo primero deberia de funcionar el forEach, si lo pusiste en el mismo lugar?

Comment: this.PesaSer.seleccionarPesajeIDTAG(idtag).subscribe(
  res.forEach((item) => {
      //a este punto 'item' contiene cada par de fecha y peso
      //aqui podrias hacer:
      this.Peso.Peso = item.peso
      //Solo ten en cuenta que este valor se sobreescribiria por cada item del arreglo
  }));
 


  
    }
Asi lo puse y me da el error

Comment: this.PesaSer.seleccionarPesajeIDTAG(idtag).subscribe(
  res=>{
   
        
    res.forEach((item) => {
      //a este punto 'item' contiene cada par de fecha y peso
      //aqui podrias hacer:
      this.Peso.Peso = item.peso
      //Solo ten en cuenta que este valor se sobreescribiria por cada item del arreglo
  });

   
        
        console.log(this.Fecha);
       
        console.log(this.Peso);

  });   ///y asi me da error en el forEach

Comment: Lo logre asi Gracias a Omar Martinez q me dio donde buscar                                               
       this.Pesa=res;   
      this.Pesa.forEach((item) => {
      this.Peso.push(item.Peso)
    });
      this.Fec=res;   
      this.Fec.forEach((item2) => {
      this.Fecha.push(item2.Fecha)
      });

   
        
        console.log(this.Fecha);
       
        console.log(this.Peso);